# Is there any way to contact the makers of bitcoin qt and bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

Would like to talk to the makers of bitcoin qt and bitcoin core. I have googled but cant find an email address or a way of contact!

Answer (score 5):

It's open source software by many independently cooperating developers. The name is now Bitcoin Core, where bitcoin-qt is the GUI application.

Discussions happen on many forums and media, so it depends a little on what kind of message you want to send them.

"Official" website: https://bitcoincore.org/ and http://bitcoin.org

All others I mention here are public media where many people participate, including some of the Core developers (not always by their real name). Always be wary of fake user IDs.

- Stackexchange: you found it already
- IRC: #bitcoin, #bitcoin-dev, ...
- Forum: http://bitcointalk.org
- Reddit: http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin

Be careful that there are a lot of companies and groups with confusing names or even purposely misleading names, trying to give themselves credibility.

Answer (score 3):

If your contact request is of a technical nature, you can also use the [github issue tracker](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/) and [create a ticket](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/new).

Keep in mind the [guidelines](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) of reporting issues, interesting part quoted:

> Firstly in terms of structure, there is no particular concept of “Core developers” in the sense of privileged people. Open source often naturally revolves around meritocracy where longer term contributors gain more trust from the developer community. However, some hierarchy is necessary for practical purposes. As such there are repository “maintainers” who are responsible for merging pull requests as well as a “lead maintainer” who is responsible for the release cycle, overall merging, moderation and appointment of maintainers.